# Vuex - passing multiple parameters to mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to authenticate a user using vuejs and laravel's passport.
**I am not able to figure out how to send multiple parameters to the vuex mutation via an action.**
**- store -**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isAuth: !!localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn(state) {
      return state.isAuth
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    authenticate(token, expiration) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)
      localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    authenticate: ({
      commit
    }, token, expiration) => commit('authenticate', token, expiration)
  }
})
```

**- login method -**

```
login() {
  var data = {
    client_id: 2,
    client_secret: '**************************',
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: this.email,
    password: this.password
  }
  // send data
  this.$http.post('oauth/token', data)
    .then(response => {
      // send the parameters to the action
      this.$store.dispatch({
        type: 'authenticate',
        token: response.body.access_token,
        expiration: response.body.expires_in + Date.now()
      })
    })
}
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Mutations expect two arguments: `state` and `payload`, where the current state of the store is passed by Vuex itself as the first argument and the second argument holds any parameters you need to pass.

The easiest way to [pass a number of parameters](https://www.karltarvas.com/2017/09/07/vuex-passing-multiple-parameters-to-an-action.html) is to [destruct them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```js
mutations: {
    authenticate(state, { token, expiration }) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration);
    }
}
```

Then later on in your actions you can simply

```js
store.commit('authenticate', {
    token,
    expiration,
});
```

Comment: It doesn't _expect_ the second argument, it's optional.

Comment: What the paramaters for `action`

Comment: Could you add how would you call the mutation or action from an external component passing the parameters?

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC The example is the same as the one for actions, except instead of `store`, you'll need to reference `this.$store`.

Comment: ": expected".. cannot be done like that

Answer (score 162):

In simple terms you need to build your payload into a key array

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Then send the payload directly to the action

```
this.$store.dispatch('yourAction', payload)
```

No change in your action

```
yourAction: ({commit}, payload) => {
  commit('YOUR_MUTATION',  payload )
},
```

In your mutation call the values with the key

```
'YOUR_MUTATION' (state,  payload ){
  state.state1 = payload.key1
  state.state2 =  payload.key2
},
```

Comment: for simple use you can do after ES6 

'YOUR_MUTATION' (state, { key1, key2 } ){
  state.state1 = key1
  state.state2 =  key2
},

Answer (score 19):

i think this can be as simple
let as assume that you are going to pass multiple parameters to you action as you read up there actions accept only two parameters `context` and `payload` which is your data you want to pass in action so let take an example

**Setting up Action**

**instead of**

```js
actions: {
        authenticate: ({ commit }, token, expiration) => commit('authenticate', token, expiration)
    }
```

**do**

```js
actions: {
        authenticate: ({ commit }, {token, expiration}) => commit('authenticate', token, expiration)
    }
```

**Calling (dispatching) Action**

**instead of**

```js
this.$store.dispatch({
                  type: 'authenticate',
                  token: response.body.access_token,
                  expiration: response.body.expires_in + Date.now()
              })
```

**do**

```js
this.$store.dispatch('authenticate',{
                  token: response.body.access_token,
                  expiration: response.body.expires_in + Date.now()
              })
```

hope this gonna help