# Passing multiple parameters to Vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have the following method in my Vue Component

```
loadMaintenances (query = {}) {
  this.getContractorMaintenances(this.urlWithPage, query).then((response) => {
    this.lastPage = response.data.meta.last_page
  })
}
```

I want to pass the parameters `(this.urlWithPage, query)` to my Vuex action as follows:

```
actions:{
  async getContractorMaintenances ({ commit }, url, query) {
    console.log(url);
    console.log(query);
    let response = await axios.get(url)

    commit('PUSH_CONTRACTOR_MAINTENANCES', response.data.data)

    return response
  },
}
```

The problem is that the first parameter `url` is returning a value but the second one `query` is returning `undefined`.

My mutation is as follows:

```
mutations: {
  PUSH_CONTRACTOR_MAINTENANCES (state, data) {
    state.contractor_maintenances.push(...data)
  },
}
```

How can I get a value from the second parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097687/vuex-passing-multiple-parameters-to-mutation) also applies to `actions`, **it expects two arguments**: `context` and `payload`.

In order to pass multiple values you'll have to send the data across as an object and destructure them:

```
async getContractorMaintenances ({ commit }, { url, query }) {
```

Comment: When I do `async getContractorMaintenances ({commit} , { url, query }) {
            console.log(url);
            console.log(query);`  both url and query are returned as undefined.

Comment: Are you passing it an object with `url` and `query` properties?

Comment: How do I pass them as an object? I'm not understanding that part. My url `http://127.0.0.1?page=1` and query `{status=new}`

Comment: It would have to be in the form of `const payload = { url: 'http://127.0.0.1?page=1', query: 'status=new' }`